# GCD of polynomials in $\mathbb Z_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

> I have to find the $\gcd(p(x),h(x))$ where $p(x)=1+2x+x^2+3x^3$ and $h(x)=2+x+x^5+x^6$ are in $\mathbb Z_5$.

To find the solution, I divide $h(x)/p(x)$ and I get $q_1(x)=2x^3+3x^2-1$ and $r_1(x)=3x^2+3x+3$

Should I divide $p(x)/r_1(x)$ ?

I think $r_1(x)$ is irreducible but I don't know what to conclude from this .

Also the answer of the exercise is $\gcd(p(x),h(x))=2$ but I don't know how to get $2$.

Comment: Yes, that's right: divide $p$ by $r_1$. You should follow through the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Procedure).

Comment: I get $q_2(x)=x+1$ and $r_2(x)=x+3$

Comment: Great. Now, do $r_1/r_2$.  What remainder do you get?

Comment: the remainder is 1. ?

Comment: Well if that's the case, then your gcd should be 1.... strange.  To be fair, $2$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z_5$, so a gcd of 2 is consistent

Comment: So this is the main process, to divide polynomial by polynomial until find a number as remainder (which will be the gcd). And in this case the numbers should be {0,1,2,3,4}. right?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Divide the polynomial until you have a zero remainder.  The last non-zero remainder is the gcd.

Comment: that's right, I've just made an analogy with the euclidean algorithm for real numbers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCD doesn't change if you multiply $p$ by $2$, so to get
$$
2+4x+2x^2+x^3
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
2+x+x^5+x^6
$$
The first remainder is $3x^2+x$, but we can multiply it by $2$:
$$
2x+x^2
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
2+4x+2x^2+x^3
$$
The remainder is $4x+2$, but we can multiply it by $4$:
$$
x+3
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
2x+x^2
$$
The remainder is $3$.

Thus the two polynomials are coprime. Answering $3$, $2$ or $1$ for the GCD is the same, as it is determined up to an invertible element.